# Filter off some elements away from php object

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Not sure if this is a php or cakephp question. I am using cakephp ver3.1.3. I have a cakephp query object `$query` that look like this when I call `debug($query->toArray());`

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {

        'id' => (int) 1,
        'username' => 'asd',
        'password' => '123',
        'fullname' => 'asd',
        'email_addr' => 'asd@gmail.com',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Customers'

    }
]
```

When I call `json_encode($query)`, it looks like this;

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "asd",
        "password": "123",
        "fullname": "asd",
        "email_addr": "asd@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

How do I process $query such that when I call `json_encode($query)`, the output will look like this?

```
[
    {
        "email_addr": "asd@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: Use json_decode and json_encode function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only receive the field 'email_addr' from the database, modify your query using the method [`select()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-all-fields-from-a-table):

```
$query->select(['email_addr']);
```

If you want to remove all other fields after the query already ran, you can just loop over the array and modify the elements:

```
$simplified = array();
foreach($query as $row) {
    $simplified[] = array(
        'email_addr' => $row->get('email_addr')
    );
}
echo json_encode($simplified);
```

On a side note, an important warning: **Do not, under no circumstance, store passwords in clear text.** Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication/477578#477578), specifically the section about storing passwords!

Comment: While the second part of @LarsEbert's answer will work for entities you have already loaded, there's a simpler method: [use the `$_hidden` property](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-properties) in the Customer entity to set which fields should not be encoded.

For example, in your Customer entity class definition:

    `protected $_hidden = ['id', 'username', 'password', 'fullname'];`